# Anthology of horror short stories in 2002. Boy becomes monster with makeup. Neighbors have to give up something to stay in neighborhood

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

One story was about a guy that found Halloween makeup and when he put it on he became that creature like a werewolf. Another was a family moved to a neighborhood but realized everything was going good until they realized everyone who lived there had to give something up, like your wife's finger. I can only vaguely remember another one, but I'll try.

- A woman was cooking a pie then went in to labor.
- When stepping outside, your feet would sink in the ground.
- When trying to get out of town they thought they made it in a van with a clown in it but as they drove off the van ate them.

Weird I know, but really wish I could find this book.

Answer (score 3):

[image: cover]

I think this is [Blue World by Robert R. McCammon](http://www.robertmccammon.com/novels/blue_world.html). It is a collection of short horror stories which includes a man who finds makeup which turns the wearer into a monster. There's also a story that ends with a van eating some people. If it's not this exact anthology, I would look and see if he has other collections of short stories.

## Synopsis

> "The skeleton was wearing Sarah's pale blue nightgown, and what looked like dried-up pieces of tree bark---skin, he realized, yes...her skin---lay all around, on and between the white bones. The teeth grinned, and from the bed there was the bittersweet odor of a damp graveyard.
> "Oh..." he whispered, and he stood staring down at what was left of his wife as his eyes began to bulge from their sockets...."
>
> Robert R. McCammon's horror novels include such modern classics of the genre as Baal and Stinger. Blue World is his first short fiction collection, an outstanding showcase of his unique power to shock, terrify and disturb the reader. Containing thirteen varied pieces, some of which have not been previously published, Blue World is modern horror fiction at its compelling best. It demonstrates superbly why critics have compared McCammon's work with that of such other giants of terror as Stephen King and Peter Straub.